# Finding distance using orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am not quite sure, I can use the orthogonal projection right. My question is, if there is a simple way, how to find a distance between two skew lines when given only a 2 points and directives of those lines, using the orthogonal projection.

For example: If I take two skew lines $p$ and $q$, where $p$ is determined by the point $[6, 3, - 3]$ and directive $(- 3, 2, 4)$, and the line $q$ is determined by the point $[- 4 - 4, 12]$ and directive $(- 3, 3, 8)$, what is their distance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [distance between lines in the space (with calculus)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56588/distance-between-lines-in-the-space-with-calculus)

Comment: Note that although the asker of the "duplicate" question was expecting a different kind of answer than you are expecting, [this answer to that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/57969/139123) is based on ideas of orthogonal projection. Was it a useful answer?

Comment: Nice Q/A, but I need help specifically with othogonal projection ;)

Comment: [Here is another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1182349/139123) which is (implicitly) based on ideas of orthogonal projection. It describes a vector that performs an orthogonal projection of one of the oblique lines onto a plane containing the second line and parallel to both lines.

Comment: what does it mean for lines to be oblique? i have heard of skew lines in $R^3$ meaning nonplanar lines that don't meet. like some of the edges of a cube. are you using oblique lines in the sense of skew lines?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you two solutions one involving orthogonal projection and one solving a linear equation - you may choose which one you like better.

### Orthogonal Projection:

One point ($\vec{p}_1$) and the two directives define a plane if they are linearily independent i.e. $ \vec{v}_1\times a=\vec{v}_2$ can only be solved by $a=0$, otherwise they define a line. Anyways the shortest distance is the orthogonal projection of the other point ($\vec{p}_2$) to this plane/line. In the following I will assume that they are linearily independent as you said the lines were oblique.

For this one first needs to orthogonalize the two directives:
$$
\vec{v}_3 = \vec{v}_1-\dfrac{\vec{v}_2\left(\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2\right)}{\vec{v}_2^2}
$$
Then the distance can then be calculated by the orthogonal projection to the plane:
$$
\vec{a} = \vec{p}_1-\vec{p}_2 \\
\vec{d} = \vec{a} - \dfrac{\vec{v}_3\left(\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{a}\right)}{\vec{v}_3^2} - \dfrac{\vec{v}_2\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{v}_2\right)}{\vec{v}_2^2}\\
\text{distance}= \lvert\lvert \vec{d} \rvert\rvert
$$

### Linear Equation

$x$ and $y$ are variables, the two lines are defined by the point $\vec{p}_1$ and the directive $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ and $\vec{v}_2$ respectively.
Therefore the distance between to points is:
$$
\lvert\lvert\left(\vec{p}_1+x\,\vec{v}_1\right) - \left(\vec{p}_2+y\,\vec{v}_2\right)\rvert\rvert
$$
The minimum distance is therefore:
$$
\mathrm{min}{\left(\lvert\lvert\left(\vec{p}_1+x\,\vec{v}_1\right) - \left(\vec{p}_2+y\,\vec{v}_2\right)\rvert\rvert\right)}
$$
The minimum in the absolute value is the same as the square root of the absolute squared:
$$
\sqrt{\mathrm{min}{\left(\left(\left(\vec{p}_1+x\,\vec{v}_1\right) - \left(\vec{p}_2+y\,\vec{v}_2\right)\right)^2\right)}}
$$
To find the minimum we can set the first derivative to 0.

Comment: I have doubts about the orthogonal projection. The vectors $\dfrac{\vec{v}_3\left(\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_2\right)}{\vec{v}_3^2}$ and $\dfrac{\vec{v}_2\left(\vec{v}_3\cdot\vec{v}_2\right)}{\vec{v}_2^2}$ are independent of the choice of $p_1$ and $p_2$, so depending on which values of $p_1$ or $p_2$ were chosen along the two lines, without changing the lines we can change $\vec a$ and therefore also change $\vec d$.

Comment: @DavidK Oh yes you are right I have an error there, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Let your first line be defined by $p_0 + t \vec v$ and the second line 
by $q_0 + t \vec w$.
Consider the vector $\vec v_\perp = \vec v \times \vec w$. 
The vector $\vec v_\perp$ is perpendicular to both
$\vec v$ and $\vec w$.

Now consider a vector $\vec u$ defined by $p_0 + \vec u = q_0$
(that is, take the line segment from $p_0$ to $q_0$ and make a vector $u$ of the same
length as that segment parallel to that segment).

Project $\vec u$ orthogonally onto $\vec v_\perp$.
Call the resulting vector $\vec u_\perp$.
Confirm that the image of the line $p$ under a translation by the vector $\vec u_\perp$
is a line intersecting the line $q$. 
Confirm that the translation is an orthogonal projection
onto the plane containing $q$ and the image of $p$.
What does that tell you about the distance between the closest points
on the lines $p$ and $q$?